# How can I do generic function with return TypedEmitter<T>

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to make a tiny system that hold emitter for specific interface like this.

I am using https://github.com/binier/tiny-typed-emitter

Please help me what I am do wrong. Thanks you alot.

```js
interface IEvenListener
{
}

interface IPlayerJoinedListener extends IEvenListener
{
    onPlayerJoined: (playerId: string) => void;
}

let emitter: TypedEmitter = ...;

function getEmitter<T extends IEvenListener>(): TypedEmitter<T> // error here
{
    return emitter as TypedEmitter<T>;
}

const messageEmitter = getEmitter<IPlayerJoinedListener>();
```

But it print out error

```
Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'ListenerSignature<T>'.
Type 'IEvenListener' is not assignable to type 'ListenerSignature<T>'.ts(2344)
```

Comment: `getEmitter<T extends ListenerSignature<T>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```js
getEmitter<T extends ListenerSignature<T>>
```